# jquery .click href

Tags: jquery, href

anyone know why it doesn't work??

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#main').click(function() {
    alert('foobar');
    document.location.href='02.html';  
    });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0px; background:#f2f2f2;}
    #main {background:url(01.jpg) top center no-repeat; height:1745px; width:100%; text-   align:center; overflow-x:hidden; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

pls help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the click function in a document ready function or place your code at the bottom of your page.

the #main element doesn't exist when the script is executed.

example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#main').click(function() {

    document.location.href='02.html';
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is one thing I don't like about jQuery - it returns a valid, yet empty, object when you select no objects. I know the functionality is useful, but it's also rough on beginners and difficult to debug.